# Strings or integers for Steam IDs

Tags: sql, database, sqldatatypes

What is the preferred datatype for storing Steam IDs? These IDs are very similar to credit card numbers, but is different cases of use. Until now I'm using unsigned big integer but I'm not 100% sure yet. If the ID starts with a zero number, can cause issues? Eg ID: 76561197960287930

Comment: bigint stores numbers.  Leading 0's is a formatting issue which should be handled in the front end.. Otherwise, save it as a varchar.

Comment: This is a question for Valve.

Answer (score -1):

In general number take less space on the disk to store and on the transfer from the database to the application compared to strings. They are for the same reason  faster to compare e.g. in the `where`-clause of a query.

Have a look here for the [bytes needed to store numbers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) and [bytes to store strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html).

In the database the numbers are stored without leading zeros. You could fill up your numbers with leading zeros in your application after loading them from the database, if the numbers always have a fixed size.

But if the numbers can have leading zeros strings are easier to handle, because you do not have to implement additional logic for edgecases like leading zeros.

Comment: please explain your down vote, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: The down vot isn't mine.